# How to specify file order with Grunt?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, minimatch

I've just started using [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), and I'm trying to get the [concat](https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-concat) task to concat my files in a specific order. Here's what I've got:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
        concat: {
            options: {
                separator: ';'
            },
            dist: {
                src: ['www/js/*.js','www/js/main.js','!**/*.{min,pack}.js','!<%= concat.dist.dest %>','!<%= uglify.dist %>'],
                dest: 'www/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
            }
        },
```

I was hoping that by putting `www/js/main.js` second, it would move the file down to the bottom of the list, but that doesn't appear to be the case.

How can I impose some order on the list of files it matches?

Comment: What's `[minimatch]` and how is it relevant to your question?  It's mentioned in passing only once in an answer, and then without any context.  It's not clear how it requires a new tag.

Comment: [minimatch](https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch) is the de-facto file matching library used internally by node/npm and many node-based projects. It's also used by Grunt. It's relevant because the `src` array is passed off to it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Your problem is that `main.js` is matched by the first pattern so the second pattern is made redundant. This might seem like a hacky way of doing it but basically *you have to exclude it* from the first pattern **before** you include it in the second; like so:

```
    concat: {
        options: {
            separator: ';'
        },
        dist: {
            src: ['www/js/*.js', '!www/js/main.js', 'www/js/main.js','!**/*.{min,pack}.js','!<%= concat.dist.dest %>','!<%= uglify.dist %>'],
            dest: 'www/js/<%= pkg.name %>.js'
        }
    }
```

**Note that when using minimatch pattern order is important.**

Answer (score 5):

I just found https://github.com/miensol/grunt-concat-in-order.

With that you could create a main js file, where you specify the order of your other javascript files with multiple @depend expressions.